# Django Allauth redirection after authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have two django projects. One is using drf and has allauth. The other project serves the HTML and is the front-end. Front-end server calls the drf API for every functionality. Front-end project is not connected to the DRF project databse.

When user clicks on Facebook, a request goes to allauth URLs on DRF server. But how do I manage the redirection after authentication? Because I have to redirect to the Front-end server and not the server on which allauth is running.

Comment: Allauth will respect Django's [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting, or you can add a `next` parameter to the redirection URL you provide Facebook, or you can configure allauth to do [dynamic redirects](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects). All of that works regardless of the domain name. Or is that you're worried about the authentication cookie not getting passed to your front-end server?

Comment: The later. I am not able to think of a way to pass on the auth token to the browser.